# Jquery not defined,getting not defined error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am getting the above error.

Following is my code

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />;
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
```

Above one is my code and I have included all the libraries related to jquery and validate.min.js too.Still I am getting the same error.

[image]

Above is the picture of errors I a getting.

Below one is the script code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("hello");
  $.ajax({
    url: "dbconnect",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      field1: "countries"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert("yes");
      var values = [];
      values = data;
      alert("success");
      alert(values);
      var option = '';

      $.each(values, function(index, value) {

        option += '<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>';
      });
      $('#countryId').append(option);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("Status: " + textStatus);
      alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
$(function() {
  $('#countryId').on('change', function() {
    var r = $('#countryId').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "dbconnect",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        field1: "states",
        field2: $('#countryId option:selected').text()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert("yes");
        var values = [];
        values = data;
        alert("success");
        alert(values);
        var option = '';
        $('#stateId').find('option')
          .remove()
          .end().append('<option value="Choose State">Choose State</option>');
        $.each(values, function(index, value) {

          option += '<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>';
        });
        $('#stateId').append(option);
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus);
        alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
      }
    });
  })
});
$(function() {
  $('#stateId').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "dbconnect",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        field1: "cities",
        field2: $('#stateId option:selected').text()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert("yes");
        var values = [];
        values = data;
        alert("success");
        alert(values);
        var option = '';
        $('#cityId').find('option')
          .remove()
          .end().append('<option value="Choose City">Choose City</option>');
        $.each(values, function(index, value) {
          alert(index + ": " + value);
          option += '<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>';
        });
        $('#cityId').append(option);
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus);
        alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
      }
    });
  })
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '1900:2017',
  });
});
```

Why I am getting the error?Is there any solution?

Comment: You load jQuery twice. Remove `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Also only necessary to have one $(function(.... )); instead of `$(document).ready(function() {` and the other $(functions - I would also refactor the ajax function to do either state or country on the same code because DRY

Comment: The message tells you exactly what's wrong and when inspecting for proper jQuery inclusion, you can see it there twice.

Comment: I also see no reason to tag this question with jQuery Validate when you show no code relevant to this plugin. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Please put your code in end of after body tag complete.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />;
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading jQuery multiple times which is actually causing the datepicker and validate not defined error.

here is a sample working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/lrZ2u8Wag4efIMi304Lq?p=preview)

While you are loading any script into any html page it is always a good practice to put the scripts in the body section(just before the body tag ends) and wrap the code within

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // your code goes here
});
```

You have written `$(function(){})` somewhere and again you are writing `$(document).ready(function(){})` they both are same so you can wrap them all in a single `document.ready` function.

One suggestion though please avoid the use of so much alerts in your application you can use console.log to simply log the error or success message to console.